# findBy to search inside an array in MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java, findby, mongorepository

I have a Mongo document which is like this :

```
db.user.find()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("560fa0c730a8e74bbd69c094"),
        "name" : "abc",
        "employee" : [{
                        "_id" : BinData(3,"v0m0V46pok94fVfwGkFVig=="),
                        "team" : "Dev Engineer",
                      }]
}

class User
{
  String name;
  String id;
}

class Employee
{
  UUID id;
  String team;
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String>
{

   @Query(value = "{ 'employee._id' : ?0 }")
    Medication findByEmployeeId(UUID Id);
}
```

I want to find the employee by id and write a find method using the employee._id. Is there anyway to do this using MongoRepository, or should I return the entire array and loop through it? I tried the above method findByEmployeeId(UUID Id), but it does not work. I am not sure if the @Query annotation is necessary here. Please suggest!